# Sql Server Connection C#: max number of insert queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlconnection

I've a problem with SqlConnection in C#. I do a large number of INSERT NonQuery, but in any case SqlConnection save in the database always the first 573 rows. This is the method I use for queries. In this method there is a lock because I use different thread to save the data.

```
   public void InsertElement(string link, string titolo, string text)
    {
        string conString = "*****************";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            text = text.Replace("\"", "");
            DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;

            lock (thisLock)
            {
                string query = "IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Result " +
                " WHERE Link = '" + link + "')) " +
                " BEGIN " +
                " INSERT INTO Result ([Titolo],[Link],[Descrizione],[DataRicerca],[FKDatiRicercheID]) " +
                " VALUES('" + titolo + "', '" + link + "', '" + text + "', '" + localDate + "', 1) " +
                " END";

                if (connection != null)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code of the loop that call the method InsertElement()

```
public void Save()
{
    string[] DatiLetti;
    string url = "";

    while (result.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            url = result.Last();
            result.RemoveAt(result.Count - 1);

            DatiLetti = ex.DirectExtractText(url);

            if (DatiLetti[0].Length > 2)
            {
                ssc.InsertGare(url, DatiLetti[0], DatiLetti[1]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            logger.Error("Exception SpiderSave> " + exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Result is a volatile array that is progressively filled from other thread. I'm sure that the array contains more than 573 items.

I try to search one solution, but all the answers say that the number of database connections for SQLServer is over 32K at a time and I've already checked this number in my database. Is there anyone who can help me understand the problem?

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to call this method in a loop and recreate the connection every time. Create the connection once and pass it to the method doing the database transaction.

Comment: How many records should be saved? Does the loop finish due to an error/exception - if so can you give details. Can you also show the loop where you call this method.

Comment: @PaulF I save an indefinite number of data. It depends by the search result.

Comment: Look into [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ... this is basically what @TomTom suggests and combine with the advice from Suman and WynDiesel.

Comment: You didn't say whether or not you get an exception to terminate the loop prematurely? Have you stepped through with the debugger (a bit tedious for a large number of records, I know - but a counter & conditional breakpoint can help) to see if records after the 537th appear to be added? _"I'm sure that the array contains more than 573 items."_ - have you confirmed that more than 537 of the result set need adding? How do you know that only 537 records are added - is it possible that all are added but you only get returned 537 for some reason?

Comment: I tried to make 1000 query insert in a loop and it works! I understand that there are other problems in my code. Thanks for the help, I will follow your advice to optimize my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing `InsertElement()` once for each rows of data to insert, then the execution will be too slow for large no. of rows. (Also, you are creating `SqlConnection` for each query execution.) Try adding many rows at once using a single INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO tablename
(c1,c2,c3)
VALUES
(v1,v2,v3),
(v4,v5,v6)
...
```

Comment: Doing individual inserts will be slow & your solution is an improvement - but it does not account for only inserting 537 rows. Each insert command will be treated separately by the server & so it should not timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't do one query for multiple values because for each value I check if this already exist in database.

Comment: Actually you can - insert into a temporary table, move into final table WHILE CHECKING. This is SQL basics, only a little higher than "write a sql statement that isnerts rows".

Answer (score 1):

Don't open a connection for every insert. Use one connection, then pass that connection through to your insert, like this :

```
public void InsertElement(string link, string titolo, string text, SqlConnection conn)
{
    text = text.Replace("\"", "");
    DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;

    lock (thisLock)
    {
        string query = "IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Result " +
                        " WHERE Link = '" + link + "')) " +
                        " BEGIN " +
                        " INSERT INTO Result ([Titolo],[Link],[Descrizione],[DataRicerca],[FKDatiRicercheID]) " +
                            " VALUES('" + titolo + "', '" + link + "', '" + text + "', '" + localDate + "', 1) " +
                            " END";

        if (connection != null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend also looking at paramatizing your query, as well as using bulk inserts, and not individual inserts

Comment: *"... dramatize your query, ..."* made my day. Auto-correct is adorable.

Comment: @Filburt, I blindly accepted google's spelling correction. Fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've passed the connection variable but I've the same problem.

Comment: @Stefano, what if you remove the lock? Are you still getting an error that there's too many connections to the database?

Comment: @WynDiesel I've removed the lock, but I've the same problem.

Comment: @Stefano What exactly is "the problem"? Are you getting an error message? Can you show us the code that's calling this function?